# Disabling snapped view 

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is there a way to disable the snapped view mode in a Windows 8 Metro application?

Edit: What I wanted to do was to not allow the user to snap the application at all.

Comment: I don't think you can disable snapped view, but instead you should be programming your app to react correctly when it goes to snapped view (for games, pausing the game might be a good idea).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent/disable snapped view for Windows 8 Metro UI applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240421/how-to-prevent-disable-snapped-view-for-windows-8-metro-ui-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, however I saw in MSDN that if you want the application to be accepted, your application must be snap-able, and that a user must always be able to snap the app. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winappswithcsharp/thread/6a503769-2e6e-4abe-a18c-4200ad568bff

Answer (score 0):

you can remove StoryBoard snippet  from 'Snapped' ViewState  in the xaml .So that when it snapped nothing will happen

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I saw in MSDN that if you want the application to be accepted your application must be snap-able, and that a user can always snap the app.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winappswithcsharp/thread/6a503769-2e6e-4abe-a18c-4200ad568bff

Comment: Note that this does not disable snapping. It merely ignores it.